# Ionic 2 on-drag

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, draggable, drag

I have a little open source [library of components](https://github.com/spike886/angular-touch-widgets) that work with touch gestures made using ionic on-drag, on-drag-start, on-drag-end directives (because they work on mobile).
Now i'm trying to port it to angular 2. But i can't find how to do that with ionic 2.
Here's the code from the Angular 1 version

```
  .directive('clockEditor', function () {
return {
  restrict: "E",
  scope: { from: '=', to: '=' },
  template:'<div on-drag-start="onTouch($event)" on-drag-end="onRelease()" on-drag="drag($event)">\
            </div>',
  controller: function($scope){

    $scope.onTouch = function(event){
      // code
    };

    $scope.onRelease = function(){
      // code
    };

    $scope.drag = function(event){
      // code
    };
  }
}
```

This is from angular 2 version

```
import {Component, OnChanges, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'clock-editor',
    template: `
    <div style="margin: auto; height: 250px; width: 350px;" draggable="true" (dragstart)="onTouch($event)" (dragend)="onRelease()" (drag)="drag($event)">
    </div>`,
})
export class ClockEditor implements OnChanges, OnInit {

    onTouch(event){
      // code
    };

    onRelease(){
      // code
    };

   drag(event){
      // code
    };
}
```

Comment: what is the problem/error you're running into?

Comment: it's just not working like in angular 1, i don't know how to make it work

Comment: not sure why you are trying to get touch/drag functionality, this is already built into ionic 2 http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures